# A phrase or idiom about living one life

Tags: meaning, idioms

I have a question about a phrase (an idiom), which can be roughly said as:

> You have only one life (to live) and it's not going to happen again.

I'm not sure if it's correct, most likely not. What I want is a meaning of this phrase, not said like "*You have only one*" but like "*Life is just one*" or "*One has only one*" if you know what I mean. Not saying to someone: "*You have*" but saying it like a general statement ("*One have*" or "*There's a...*"). Something like:

> One has only one life and it's not going to happen again (or repeat).

I thought about replacing the part "happen again" with something like "repeat" which would suit better from my point of view but as far as I searched the web, it's not used in this kind of phrase.

Suggestions for more less widely used or known phrases welcomed.

Answer (score 2):

This is usually rendered as

> I have but one life to live.

Nathan Hale famously turned this around as he was about to be executed by the British:

> I only regret that I have but one life to lose for my country.

Comment: My high-school typing teacher modified this slightly and referred to the "*" as the "Nathan Hale" key.  Of course we asked why, and he explained that as Nathan Hale was about to be executed, he said: "I only regret that I have but one asterisk for my country."

Answer (score 2):

> I've only got one life, and one pair of hands.

is a version of this saying that you may remember if you're familiar with the video or audiobook *Mr. Bach Comes to Call* (see transcript 1:39-1:44 of 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0U-t0UxHopg).

Answer (score 1):

How about

> We only go around once.

or even as straightforward as

> You only live once.

(There is a Bond movie that suggests otherwise, however.)

EDIT:

You also asked for a "not you" phrase, which I haven't provided.  How about

> The clock of life is wound but once.

I think this is a line from a Robert Smith poem.

Comment: As I recall, the Schlitz Brewing Company ran a campaign with the following slogan: "You only go around once in life, so do it with gusto. Schlitz - go for the gusto!"

Comment: My favorite is: You only live once - but if you do it right, once is enough.

Comment: You only live once - but if you drink Schlitz, once is enough. :-)

Answer (score 1):

***carpe diem***

This is not an English phrase, to be sure, though it is well-known to English speakers. In my opinion -- thanks to *Dead Poets Society* -- it is a hackneyed phrase, but it captures something of what you want to convey.

Originally from Horace *Odes 1.11*:

> Carpe diem, quam minimum credula
>   postero
>
> *Seize the day trusting as little as possible in tomorrow*

Simply put: "Live it up, 'cause you only go 'round once"

Answer (score 1):

How about "Que sera, sera", or in English

> Whatever will be, will be.

It avoids a direct address, and can be used in the same sense of "you don't know what is going to happen, so you might as well try"